# Using unlist inside a function call

Tags: r, loops, screen-scraping, rvest

I am trying to create a dataset based on web scraping across a numbers of URLs.

For this example, I am trying to scrape the node called `h2.title`, which is a child node to `li.portal_list_item`. I.e., I wish to create *one* vector containing all the values of the node (500 on each URL).

I wish to do this inside a loop or function.

A subset of the URLs is,

```
test_urls <- c("https://projekter.aau.dk/projekter/da/studentthesis/search.html?showAdvanced=true&advanced=true&pageSize=500&page=1",
               "https://projekter.aau.dk/projekter/da/studentthesis/search.html?showAdvanced=true&advanced=true&pageSize=500&page=2")
```

Right now, I can scrape the nodes and I acquire a list of lists - 2 of 500. However, I want to `unlist` this into one long vector of 1000 *inside* the function, so I can also use the function to create a dataset, because I need to scrape across many nodes - and if I could simply get one vector, I can assign it to a column of the dataset.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

dfList <- lapply(test_urls, function(i) {
  webpage <- read_html(i)
  listitems <- html_nodes(webpage, "li.portal_list_item")
  .GlobalEnv$titles <- listitems %>% html_nodes("h2.title") %>% html_text()
})
```

If I try to use `unlist` inside my function, it simply doesn't work, which I intuitively understand - however, I can't seem to find a solution.

Any help is really, really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We can just use `collapse`

```
dfList <- lapply(test_urls, function(i) {
  webpage <- read_html(i)
  listitems <- html_nodes(webpage, "li.portal_list_item")
  titles <- listitems %>% html_nodes("h2.title") %>% html_text()
  titles = paste(titles,collapse="\n")
  return(titles)
})
```

We now have a list with two elements.